# Why I cannot access Child Object method with Parent Type

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

object a2 is of type A but references an object of class C. So, a2 should be able to access m3(). But, why is it not happening? If m3() method had been defined in class A, then the code would run fine

```
class A {

   int var = 7;

   void m1() {
      System.out.println("A's m1 ,");
   }

   void m2() {
      System.out.println("A's m2 ,");
   }
}

class B extends A {

   void m1() {
      System.out.println("B's m1 ,");
   }
}

class C extends B {

   void m3() {
      System.out.println("c's m3 ," + (var + 6));
   }
}

class Mixed {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();
      B b = new B();
      C c = new C();
      A a2 = new C();
      a2.m1();
      a2.m2();
      a2.m3();
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly because of what you said. `a2` is **an instance** of class `C` but it's accessed through an object of class `A` and `A` has not `m3()` method. Imagine to write `void foo(A obj) { a.m3(); }`. Do you expect it works? Of course not and here it's same.

Comment: 'a2' reference defined as A, but class 'A' have not 'm3' method. You can solve this problem by casting: ((C) a2).m3();

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti i didn't get the  "a2 is an instance of class C but it's accessed through an object of class A" part. Please explain.As far as I know, "object" and "instance" of a "class" are the same thing

Comment: -3?  Why many down votes ?? It is well formatted. Come on, be helpful.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ yes,instead of getting help, i got "down-voted"

Comment: I mean: `a2` is of class `C` but it's assigned to a variable of type `A`. You'll see only methods for variable's class (`A` in this case) unless you cast (but don't make it complicate now). Object is of type `C` but accessed through `A` (then you see only `A` methods, implemented/extended/overridden by `C` class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A a2=new C();
```

That means you can access only the members of Class `A` and implementations of Class `C`, if any overridden.

Now m3 is not a member of `A`. Clear ?

Comment: implementations of class C?

Comment: @r2b Yes. Suppose you have a method `test()` in class A and , If you ovveride that method of A in class C, then if you write `A.test()` then implementation of `test()` in Class C executes.

Comment: I have provided exactly this scenario in my answer.

Comment: @JamesB Oh my twin brother :). That's the same. Deserves up vote. +1.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this line

```
 A a2=new C();
```

a2 will only ever be able to access methods defined in Class A.

Even though a2 refers to an instance of Class C, it cannot invoke methods defined *only* in C.

However, if you had the following:

```
class A {
    void m3() {
        System.out.println("in A");
    }
}

class C extends A {
    void m3() {
        System.out.println("in C");
    }
}

...
A a2 = new C();
a2.m3();
```

would output

> in C

In this case, the m3() method is being overridden and the method invoked will be determined by the type of the instance which a2 refers to (i.e. C).

I would take a look at the Java tutorials here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use a *reference of the parent / superclass* and try to invoke a method on the subclass, then that method should be defined in the *parent / superclass*. i.e, *what* methods you can call on the object(rhs) depends on the lhs (reference type).

Answer (score 0):

Compiler checks reference of object which is invoking a method...
In your case `A a2=...` is what compiler can see, and it finds that there is no `m3()` method defined in `A` class. Hence code will not compile.

Note that,
While invoking method at runtime, JVM refers the object referenced by the Reference. In your case *Reference of class A is referring Object of class C.*

Read more at : [Polymorphism in Java](http://java8.in/polymorphism-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You see the subclass `C` as an instance of `A` because an `A` does not have the function `m3` that a `C` has.

```
  A a2 = new C();
```

So here, you can access only the methods in `C` that are inherited from `A`. You basically see it as an `A`. If you wanted to call the methods in `C`, you would have to `cast` it to `C`,  so you'd have to do something like this:

```
 if(a2 instanceof C)
 {
     C castedA2 = (C)a2;
     castedA2.m3();
 }
```