# Why is casting required in Inheritance

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance, casting

*

```
class Abc {
    void m1() {
    }
}
class Bat extends Abc {
    void m2() {
    }
}
class Cat extends Bat {
    void m3() {
    }
}
class D extends Cat {
    void m4() {
    }
}
public class Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abc a = new Bat();
        a.m1();
        ((Bat) a).m2();
    }
}
```

Why are we casting the created object to `Bat` in order to access `m2()` when that method is of `Bat` class and we have created its `object` also??

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032659/why-i-cannot-access-child-object-method-with-parent-type?rq=1) more.

Answer (score 0):

the `m2` method is not defined as a method on the assigned type `Bat`, which will therefore result in compile time issue; this could be solved by casting;

Although a new instance of `Cat` was created, its reference is by a which is declared to be of the type `Abc`. Therefore, any references to a makes the new `Cat` be handled as an `Abc`.